# Condition for comparing two arrays

Tags: php

I have two variables that return various Id numbers. I intend that when the value exists in the two variables that I update the database, if the value only exists in one, I do insert.
For example the variables will return the following values:

```
$N_utente1(1,2,3,4,5,6)

$N_utente(1,2,4,5,7)
```

So I want to create a condition that does the following:

If the values ​​in the variable $N_utente are equal to the values ​​of the variable $N_utente1, then it updates and in case the value of the variable $N_utente does not exist in the variable $N_utente1 then it inserts these values.

my code:

```
$query1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT N_utente FROM raddb.Areceber");
$query1->execute();

while($row=$query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    
    $N_utente1 = $row["N_utente"];

    $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $file_open = fopen($file,"r");
    while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false){
         $N_utente = $csv[1];

    if($N_utente == $N_utente1){
      $query = 'UPDATE Areceber SET N_utente= ? WHERE N_utente = ? ';
      $conn->prepare($query)->execute([$N_utente, $$N_utente]);
    }else{
      $query = 'INSERT INTO Areceber (Id_linha, N_utente) 
      VALUES ( ?, ?)';
      $stmt= $conn->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute([$Id, $N_utente]);
    }
    }
}
```

What I want is for the condition to compare the two values ​​line by line and if true, update, if false, insert

Comment: Create and fill N_utente  before the loop. It does not change while the loop runs.  And in the loop `if in_array($N_utente1, $N_utente) ....`

Comment: @splash58 This way you are inserting the new lines, but not updating the lines that change. I intend that when making the condition, it checks line by line and inserts or updates according to the result of the condition line by line. Did you understand?

Comment: @splash5 For example, it goes through the first line or the first loop, if true, it does update. goes through the second line or the second loop, in case of false insert and so on until the end of the loop. It's possible?

Comment: if in array - update else insert ? or it's wrong

Comment: @splash58 It's not wrong, but it's just inserting the new N_utente, but I also changed N_utente values ​​but it's not updating during the loop

Comment: "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" is not an option ?

Comment: @splash58 It already worked. I was changing a field that was not updating the query. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```html
   <pre>    
 use this code I think it will work

for ( $j = 0; $j <= count($a)||$j <= count($b); $j+1 ) {
  if (a[$j]  == b[$j] ) {
    //
} else {
  //
}
}

</pre>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).